# Are complex expressions possible in ng-hide / ng-show?

Tags: attributes, angularjs, expression

I want to do so:

```
ng-hide="!globals.isAdmin && mapping.is_default"
```

but the expression evaluates always to `false`.

I do not want to define special function on `$scope`.

Comment: That syntax works for me, and I use it frequently. If it's evaluating to `false`, you might want to double-check those values. It's possible that the "globals" and/or "mapping" objects are `undefined`

Comment: Read my comment below the answer.

Comment: just a hint - if you use controller method instead, you can actually step through the evaluation in debugger!

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Use a controller method if you need to run arbitrary JavaScript code, or you could define a filter that returned true or false.

I just tested (should have done that first), and something like `ng-show="!a && b"` worked as expected.

Comment: You are right. The problem was that the isAdmin flag was of type 'string' rather than 'boolean'.

Answer (score 125):

`ng-show` / `ng-hide` accepts only `boolean` values.

For complex expressions it is good to use controller and scope to avoid complications.

Below one will work (It is not very complex expression)

```
ng-show="User=='admin' || User=='teacher'"
```

Here element will be shown in UI when any of the two condition return true (OR operation).

Like this you can use any expressions.

Answer (score 13):

This will work if you do not have too many expressions.

Example: `ng-show="form.type === 'Limited Company' || form.type === 'Limited Partnership'"`

For any more expressions than this use a controller.

Comment: I dont think your statement is correct: `This will work if you do not have too many expressions.` although I agree that it should be done in the controller instead.

Answer (score 7):

I generally try to avoid expressions with ng-show and ng-hide as they were designed as booleans, not conditionals.  If I need both conditional and boolean logic, I prefer to put in the conditional logic using ng-if as the first check, then add in an additional check for the boolean logic with ng-show and ng-hide

Howerver, if you want to use a conditional for ng-show or ng-hide, here is a link with some examples: [Conditional Display using ng-if, ng-show, ng-hide, ng-include, ng-switch](http://realityonweb.com/angularjs-conditional-display-using-ng-show-ng-hide-ng-if-ng-include-ng-switch/)

Answer (score 2):

Some of these above answers didn't work for me but this did. Just in case someone else has the same issue.

```
ng-show="column != 'vendorid' && column !='billingMonth'"
```