# ngshow and nghide delegation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

broken demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/EWOvKsTEutiveMEAGTKf?p=preview

```
<li ng-show="showList" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-hide="task.checked=1">
  {{task.name}}
</li>
```

can I place ng-show and ng-hide on the same tag? I want to hide checked task but when I click show all list, the result would be a list that excluded checked task.

Comment: In addition to Dalorzo's answer, you've got a typo in the `ngHide` directive: `task.checked == 1` (and probably `task.checked === true`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using `and(&&)` or `or(||)` on the same attribute either `ngHide` or `ngShow` to evaluate the expression `(exp1) || (expr2)`? Like

```
ng-hide="Expr1=='something' || Expr2=='else'"
```

You can refer to this other POST for more information:

[Are complex expressions possible in ng-hide / ng-show?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15166184/1959948)

Here is a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/713deUSjNrGF4chv86Gf?p=preview)