# Angularjs - `ng-hide` with expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

How can I do an `ng-hide` inline expression like this:

```
ng-hide="userType!=user"
```

?

Comment: Just like you just did.

Comment: I just tried that and it is not working.

Comment: Then show the complete relevant code, explain what you want to achieve, what you expect the code to do and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0):

what is your userType ?? a string ? and you want to hide if != 'user'

```
ng-hide="userType!='user'"
```

please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20265905/3033318) about ng-hide/ng-show

Comment: you are doing something wrong then, show you code, make a plunker plz?

Answer (score 0):

The ngHide directive would not work on an inline expression. The inline expression is evaluated and then the result is injected in the HTML element containing the expression.

If the inline expression is just plain text, you could try the following:

```
{{ userType != user ? "" : value }}
```

or if you do not want an empty string you could also use "null"

```
{{ userType != user ? null : value }}
```